# Shapes (None, 512, 512, 3) and (None, None) are incompatible

Tags: keras, dataset, tensor

took the finished architecture from the Internet, you need a normal dataset for work, changed it to COCO and swiched and changed the settings for the photo, afterwards got this error
Dont even know what means (None, None) from where does it goes

```
ERROR:
Shapes (None, 512, 512, 3) and (None, None) are incompatible




MODEL:
def build_deep_autoencoder(img_shape, code_size):
H, W, C = img_shape
# encoder
encoder = tf.keras.models.Sequential() 
encoder.add(L.GaussianNoise(stddev=2, seed=1))
encoder.add(L.InputLayer(img_shape))  
encoder.add(L.Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='elu', padding='same'))
encoder.add(L.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
encoder.add(L.Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='elu', padding='same'))
encoder.add(L.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
encoder.add(L.Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='elu', padding='same'))
encoder.add(L.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
encoder.add(L.Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='elu', padding='same'))
encoder.add(L.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
encoder.add(L.Flatten())
encoder.add(L.Dense(code_size))

# decoder
decoder = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
decoder.add(L.InputLayer(code_size))
decoder.add(L.Dense(32 * 32 * 256))
decoder.add(L.Reshape((32, 32, 256)))
decoder.add(L.Conv2DTranspose(filters=128, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=2, activation='elu',                  padding='same'))
decoder.add(L.Conv2DTranspose(filters=64, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=2, activation='elu', padding='same'))
decoder.add(L.Conv2DTranspose(filters=32, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=2, activation='elu', padding='same'))
decoder.add(L.Conv2DTranspose(filters=3, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=2, activation='elu', padding='same'))

return encoder, decoder


encoder, decoder = build_deep_autoencoder(IMG_SHAPE, code_size=64)
decoder.summary()

inp = L.Input(IMG_SHAPE)
code = encoder(inp)
reconstruction = decoder(code)



SGD_mom_nest = keras.optimizers.SGD(
learning_rate=0.5,
momentum=(0.9),
nesterov=True
)
recall = keras.metrics.PrecisionAtRecall(0.9)

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
rescale=1. /255,
rotation_range=60,
width_shift_range=0.3,
height_shift_range=0.3,
zoom_range=0.3,
horizontal_flip=False,
vertical_flip=False,
fill_mode='nearest',
brightness_range=(1, 4),
validation_split=0.2
)

train_gen = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
"H:/caltech-101/101_ObjectCategories",
target_size=(512, 512),
batch_size=1
)



autoencoder = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=inp, outputs=reconstruction)
autoencoder.compile(optimizer=SGD_mom_nest, loss='MeanSquaredLogarithmicError', metrics=recall)
history = autoencoder.fit(train_gen, epochs=5, verbose=1,  steps_per_epoch=5)
```

Tried to change model architecture - no result, all resources says that problem in layers, but if i dont use generator and use just numpay array with the same setting for dimentions everything's works